# Converting a Array[ValueRange] to util.List[ValueRange]

Tags: java, list, scala, google-sheets-api

I am currently trying to do a batch update to a google sheet via a scala project however i am having a lot of trouble converting a Array[ValueRange] to util.List[ValueRange]

here is the code produceing the information for the body value for the batch update:

```
val values = util.Arrays.asList(util.Arrays.asList[AnyRef](
      "Y"
    ))

val data =
      allTasksToBeCompleted.map {
        id =>
          val range = s"$sheetName!G${id.toInt}:G${id.toInt}"
          new ValueRange().setRange(range).setValues(values)
      }
```

I have tried converting via util.Arrays.asList(data) and asInstanceOf however neither seems to work at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried JavaConverters decorators?

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val data = Array(1, 2, 3)
val list = data.toList.asJava
```

```
data: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
list: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

This should convert any Array[T] to java.util.List[T]

Comment: the data.toList.asJava seems to have worked thank you